# how to use jpcap?

Tags: java, netbeans

i have installed jpcap and add it in library but i have error in this line:

```
 String[] devices = JpcapCaptor.getDeviceList();
```

i think I added it wrong because it said:
Javadoc not found. Either Javadoc documentation for this item does not exist or you have not added specified Javadoc in the Java Platform Manager or the Library Manager.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException {
        // TODO code application logic here
      String[] devices = JpcapCaptor.getDeviceList();
        if(args.length<1){
            System.out.println("Usage: java SentUDP <device index (e.g., 0, 1..)>");
            for(int i=0;i<devices.length;i++)
                System.out.println(i+":"+devices[i].name+"("+devices[i].description+")");
            System.exit(0);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

See [how-to-add-jcap-jar-and-its-javadoc-into-netbeans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6256111/how-to-add-jcap-jar-and-its-javadoc-into-netbeans/6256601#6256601). It may answer you question.