# How to add jcap.jar and its Javadoc into Netbeans

Tags: java, packet, sniffing, jpcap

i want to add jpcap.jar the path is this:

```
C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\lib\ext
```

how to do this?

```
import java.lang.ClassLoader;
```

is it needed?
 or:

```
  System.loadLibrary('what must be in here?');
```

or:

```
System.load(???);
```

suppose this code:

```
public void receivePacket(Packet packet) {
System.out.println(packet);
if (packet instanceof IPPacket) {
IPPacket ipp = (IPPacket)packet;
InetAddress dest = ipp.dst_ip;
InetAddress src = ipp.src_ip;
System.out.print(src);
System.out.print(dest);
 }
```

in the main i have this:

s.receivePacket(Packet.EOF);

but it returns:

```
0.0
```

i added library with rightclick add library but i think it doesn't work cause:
i have this when selecting packet

Javadoc not found. Either Javadoc documentation for this item does not exist or you have not added specified Javadoc in the Java Platform Manager or the Library Manager

Comment: You need some classes from that jar or what? If so - what are those classes? Does C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java dir is your JAVA_HOME?

Comment: I want to use the library jpcap and the jar file I need to get packets of DHCP

Comment: the path file that i wrote is the location of jpcap.jar in my computer

Comment: the java netbeans was installed on c:/programfiles but the jpcap is on c:/windows/sun/java

Comment: So. You need to add jpcap.jar to your netbeans project?

Comment: No, you don't want to put jpcap.jar into c:\windows\sun\java\ext. That's entirely the wrong place for it. That's the place for Java Extensions, and Jpcap isn't one of those. Jpcap.jar should be placed along with your own application Jars.

Comment: @MOcker yes i need @EJP then what i must do now?

Comment: @Negin what part of my suggestion didn't you understand?

Comment: And if you got this 0.0 you must already have the jpcap DLL loaded correctly. Your question doesn't really make much sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you will find the answer on how to add jcap.jar: [how-to-add-library-files-in-netbeans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5893349/how-to-add-library-files-in-netbeans/5893518#5893518).

The absence of javadoc doesn't mean that you haven't added the library itself, because javadocs are usually in separate jars or zips.

If the code that uses library method is compiled, than the problem is not in the absence of library.

Usually, the source code of any java library, the binary files and javadoc are contained in separate jar-files, zip-files or folders.

**UPDATE:**
The soulution is:

1. download jpcap-x.x.zip from [here](http://netresearch.ics.uci.edu/kfujii/Jpcap/doc/download.html);
2. unzip it to any folder you like;
3. add the ***doc/javadoc*** subfolder of unzipped folder to your library in library manager.

[Video How-To](http://youtu.be/vqhQY7U9Rlc).

Comment: I did it and I studied it previously but no result in this code

Comment: @Negin I've updated my answer a bit. Do you have any errors while compiling your project?

Comment: no not error it is build success full showing me 0.0 but it has Javadoc not found. Either Javadoc documentation for this item does not exist or you have not added specified Javadoc in the Java Platform Manager or the Library Manager when selecting IPPACKET or Packet.etc

Comment: but then why it tells me that in explanation of IPPACKET?!

Comment: @Negin Do you know the location of javadoc for jpcap.jar? You should specify the path to library javadoc in library manager.

Comment: can you give me the differences between javadoc and classes and source in java platforms and then what is library i am confused here

Comment: @Negin Ok. Then we need more information. Can you tell us where did you get that jpcap.jar. Where can I get it?

Comment: Mocker I got it from my friend but i can send the file to you if you want or if you have another choice for me please tell me i will use it

Comment: @Negin Does [this resource](http://netresearch.ics.uci.edu/kfujii/Jpcap/doc/index.html) describes your library? Maybe you can get it there?

Comment: yes i think  i have these in the java folder of c:/programfiles==>jre1.6.0_03 and jre6 they are folders and in c:/windows/etc i have jpcap.jar

Comment: @Negin I've installed this library. The problem is that it doesn't install any javadoc on local machine. Shit happens... So you'll need to use the [online javadoc](http://netresearch.ics.uci.edu/kfujii/Jpcap/doc/javadoc/index.html).

Comment: Mocker how!? in this site i must try what?

Comment: I used librarymanager as u told but no result similer to previous

Comment: I added C:\programfiles\java\jpcap-0-6

Comment: i used to go to tools=>javaplatforms not libreries but since u told i used tools=>libraries

Comment: leave it Mocket I appreciate your help:) you tried hard for me it is my fault I'm accepting your answer

Comment: @Negin Please add to your question a scrinshot of your library configuration window's 'Javadoc' tab.

Comment: Have you solved it? I can help you via ICQ or e-mail if it's still unsolved.

Comment: how i must insert image here? i don't know please tell me

Comment: nickparsa@gmail.com do you have gmail?

Answer (score 0):

Nice to see that your problem is solved after a lot of struggle. Have a look at which4j project. It can help solve these issues quickly

Comment: which4j can be used to print the name of the jar for a given class. It will search in the classpath.  http://javafanatics.blogspot.com/2007/04/which4j.html